# Recording from multiple microphones python

Tags: python, audio-recording, pcm, alsa

I am trying to record from multiple microphones simultaneously using python. I require the recordings to almost exactly simultaneous as I am going to be cross correlating the audio signals using scipy in order to get a direction from which the sound came. So far, when I plot the results of my recorded sound on a graph, the recordings are out of sync even if the 2 mics are equidistant from the sound source. Here is my code:

```
import alsaaudio
import numpy

inp1 = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE,alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL,'Set')
inp1.setchannels(1)
inp1.setrate(44100)
inp1.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp1.setperiodsize(1024)
inp2 = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE,alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL,'Set_1')
inp2.setchannels(1)
inp2.setrate(44100)
inp2.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp2.setperiodsize(1024)

i = int(raw_input('How many samples of recording?'))
amp1 = []
amp2 = []

while i > 0:
    l, data1 = inp1.read()
    a = numpy.fromstring(data1, dtype='int16')
    amp1.extend(abs(a))
    l, data2 = inp2.read()
    b = numpy.fromstring(data2, dtype='int16')
    amp2.extend(abs(b))
    i -= 1
```

This gives me my 2 audio signals as amp1 and amp2. I am a beginner when it comes to programming and I think perhaps there is a better way to do this...

Comment: You might try adjusting the period size (setperiodsize) and set it to a lower number. The read() function blocks, so that might be causing the delay you're getting. Alternatively, you might try using a single input, but recording on 2 channels, and use one mike for each channel. If that works with your setup, you will definitely get a synchronous recording that way.

Comment: Hmmm, changing setperiodsize did not help. I'm not sure I can get both mics to behave as a single input as each USB mic is recognized as a separate sound card by Alsa.

Comment: Back when I recorded music, I would use a mono-to-stereo converter like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Monster-MCL-MST2MF-Female-Adapter/dp/B000HHJIO0/ref=sr_1_28?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1383864213&sr=1-28&keywords=mono+to+stereo+adapter) to run two microphones onto a single stereo track. I took a brief look around the net, and didn't see anything like this for USB, but it's possible you could rig something up with a series of 1/4 / USB converters. If I get a chance this weekend, I'll break out my mics and try your code out myself.

Comment: Sorry man, my old mic setup won't work with my new computer without some adapting equipment. Best luck with this, it's an interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

To force two devices to start at the same time, the ALSA C API has `snd_pcm_link`.

This function is not exposed by pyalsaaudio.